# Principal component analysis axes interpretation?

Tags: pca, interpretation

I draw this circle of correlation and I want to know the significance of variables that i circled in green
i concluded that variables ig2h are correlated of individuals (1)(the blues ones) and c2 are correlated with individuals(0) (the red ones)
but i can not conclude anything for a3,a2, ...
what is their relation with individuals (0 and 1)

[image]

Comment: Because the labels on your plot are so small it is going to be hard for anyone to help you here. Can you describe the issue you are facing in more detail?

Comment: I just noticed that you suggested some edits to this post using a different account. Please [register your account](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in order to edit your post yourself or post comment in this thread.